# itextsharp c# windows app div height and border

Tags: c#, html, itext, border

I have been trying to create a invoice bill in c# using itextsharp html to pdf. When i try to set border for table and cell, it works. But for div it does not work. Can anybody to help on this.

i construct a stringbuilder like
`sb.Append("div style='height:500px;border:1'>"); 
sb.Append("table style='height:100%' width='100%'>");`

once done i create a string out of it and use below to parse it to pdf
                    `XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, pdfDoc, sr);`

Comment: Can you add your code?

Comment: Which version of iText? The latest version available on NuGet is 7.1.0.

Comment: i use dll from itextsharp-all-5.5.10

Comment: Ah, what you need is probably not supported in that old version. You should consider using iText 7 + the [pdfHTML add-on](https://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfHTML).

Comment: is there any link from where i can download the latest, all i find is itextsharp 5.X